# Proper way to create a service provider in Laravel

Tags: laravel, service-provider, invoice-ninja

I am having trouble creating a service for my Laravel application. I wish to use this service to easily communicate with an API to perform IO operations. To be specific, my Laravel application needs to communicate with InvoiceNinja. There is an invoiceninja/sdk-php which I am using to facilitate this communication. According to [their docs](https://github.com/invoiceninja/sdk-php), it is used like this:

```
require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';

use InvoiceNinja\Config as NinjaConfig;
use InvoiceNinja\Models\Client; // Model can be Invoice, Payment, etc

NinjaConfig::setURL('https://ninja.dev/api/v1');
NinjaConfig::setToken('Your Token');

$clients = Client::all();
```

The code snippet above is an example of using the API to fetch a list of clients. Now, since I am using Laravel, I did not see the need of setting the API URL and Token every time I needed to send a request to the API. And so I decided to use a Service Provider. Below is my code in `InvoiceNinjaServiceProvider.php` register method:

```
$this->app->singleton(NinjaConfig::class, function ($app) {
    NinjaConfig::setURL(config('invoice-ninja.API_URL')); // I created a config/invoice-ninja.php which has these variables set
    NinjaConfig::setToken(config('invoice-ninja.API_TOKEN'));
});
```

I then registered this provider in `config/app.php`. I thought that would be enough to use the API in my controllers like this:

```
use InvoiceNinja\Models\Client;

public function index(InvoiceNinjaServiceProvider $invoiceNinja)
{
    $clients = Client::all();

    dd($clients); // To test that I actually receive data
}
```

But I get an error `Unresolvable dependency resolving [Parameter #0 [ <required> $app ]] in class Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider`. I am not very well versed with Service Providers and I am hoping someone out there can point me in the right direction to get this to work.

Thank you. Thank you!

Comment: You won't be able to use a singleton since the SDK will not resolve the `Config` with the Laravel container. But because it's `static`, it could work to simply call `setURL` and `setToken` in you `AppServiceProvider` without using singleton, binding or something else. Then use `Client::all()` in you `index`. Can you try it?

Answer (score 0):

You should return the resolved instance when you bind your singleton, the instance will be injected as a parameter in yout `index` method.
From the [doc](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/container#binding-a-singleton):

```
  $this->app->singleton('HelpSpot\API', function ($app) {
    return new \HelpSpot\API($app->make('HttpClient'));
});
```

note the `return`